# How to obtain a PrimaryKey projection of a TableElementType tuple?

Tags: scala, slick

Using Slick's lifted embedding, I define a class extending AbstractTable, with some primary keys spanning multiple columns. For example:

```
class Foo extends AbstractTable[(some, tuple, type)](tag, name)
{
  def col1 = ...
  def col2 = ...
  def col3 = ...
  def * = (col1, col2, col3)
  def pk = primaryKey(name, (col1, col2))
  ...
}
```

Somewhere in the code, I hold a PrimaryKey reference that corresponds to that primary key (the code in question is generic and must not depend on the knowledge of which specific tables and which columns are defined). I also hold a reference to a TableElementType tuple corresponding to a row in this table, as defined by the * projection.

How do I programmatically obtain the primary key projection of that element? That is, given the PrimaryKey and TableElementType references as arguments, I want to obtain the (val1, val2) tuple out of the (val1, val2, val3) TableElementType tuple, in this example. I didn't find readily available methods to achieve that in the Slick documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractTable` has a different signature, it takes 3 parameters and not 2:

```
abstract class AbstractTable[T](val tableTag: Tag, val schemaName: Option[String], val tableName: String) extends ColumnBase[T]
```

Here I'm extending `Table` for convenience, what you can do is twist the shape in your table type parameter:

```
class Foo(tag: Tag) extends Table[((String, String), String)](tag, "Foo") {
  def col1 = column[String]("c1")
  def col2 = column[String]("c2")
  def col3 = column[String]("c3")
  def * = ((col1, col2), col3)
  def pk = primaryKey("pk", (col1, col2))
}
```

Note that if you have `(String, String, String)` then the projection function must be also defined so:

```
def * = (col1, col2, col3)
// this below doesn't match the given shape:
// def * = ((col1, col2), col3)
```

If you don't want to, just define a custom method:

```
def someF(results: List[(String, String, String)]): List[((String, String), String)] = {
  results.map { case(a,b,c) => ((a,b),c) }
}
```

The code is untested because at the moment I don't have a database available but it compiles.

Edit:

You could use this:

```
def tupleKeys[T <: Table[S], S](table: TableQuery[T]): Tuple2[Option[PrimaryKey], Option[PrimaryKey]] = {
  val keys: List[PrimaryKey] = table.baseTableRow.primaryKeys.toList
  if(keys.length == 2) (Option(keys(0)), Option(keys(1)))
  else (Option(keys(0)), None)
}
```

But as I said, you don't know how many keys you have before running the script while the tuple has its length fixed, I wrapped the values in option because you may or not have 2 keys and you can either return a `Tuple1` or a `Tuple2` since they are different types, you can use this method into the projection function to twist the keys shape but it still won't be as dynamic as you want it.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I was asking for. I haven't even started writing classes for the concrete tables (and won't, for a while yet). I'm writing a generic data access layer, and I'm interested in a generic way to obtain primary key projections. Something like a method in a generic class that takes two arguments, PrimaryKey and T#TableElementType, and returns the tuple of the values of the given element only for the columns that are included in the primary key.

Comment: What you are asking is not easily achievable because the tuple length it's encoded in it's type (eg `Tuple2`, `Tuple3` and so on), what you can do is define a table object and get the primary keys in an iterator: `TableQuery[Foo].baseTableRow.primaryKeys`, form here I can't really tell you how to mutate this into a tuple, probably shapeless has something related, but I'm not an expert in the library.

Comment: OK, I see. I do iterate over the primary keys, of course. How about a simpler question? Say, I have a T#TableElementType element and a Column[V] column. How do I programmatically obtain that column's value for that element?

Comment: Apples and oranges in my opinion, `TableElementType` is a row representation of your database (what you get with the projection function for example), `Column` is used to create a table abstraction, although they refer to the same entity they are derived in different ways and as far as I can say there's no clear relation between the two, to the best of my knowledge slick uses some AST  to translate collection-like operations in SQL (no column). If you have already a row you already have the value in whatever shape you specified in your table definition.

Comment: So how do I retrieve that value from a row? I can't call elem.col1, because the code doesn't have access to the class and so doesn't know that the col1 method even exists. All I have, besides the row, is a PrimaryKey instance, on which I can call key.columns and iterate over the columns.

Comment: You don't call `elem.col1`, a `TableElementType` is an alias, it represent the shape you gave to your table, in your case you passed a triple as type parameter, it means that `type TableElementType = Tuple3[String, String, String]`. Why is it useful, when you execute a query the projection function will map those sql results to the shape you gave in the projection function, for example `fooTable.filter(_.id === someID).list` will return a list of triples in your case and then you can access whatever value you want, you cannot use column names... (continues)

Comment: ... you could use (and actually it's the best approach) case classes and make the shape be a case class,  the projection will map results to the class and then you can access values like class parameters. In my opinion you are trying to skin the cat without knowing how to handle the knife, you should start looking at some example projects and/or activator templates.

Comment: Please see this for more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005066/using-couchbase-as-cache-over-slick